# different templateUrl in AngularJS app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to put in my directive a way to different template, based on a $scope value. I use directive inside ng-repeat and i send her the object of datas and a other direct input

directive :

```
/**
 * angular-streamlist directive
 */
angular.module('ngStreamlist', []).directive('webcams', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            stream_webcam: '=webcam',
            stream_margin: '@margin'
        },

        templateUrl: function(elem, attr) {
            if (scope.stream_webcam.webcam_domain) {
                  if (scope.stream_webcam.webcam_domain == 'youtube') {
                      return 'templates/youtube.html';
                  }
                  if (scope.stream_webcam.webcam_domain == 'twitcam') {
                      return 'templates/twitcam.html';
                  }
            }
        }

    };
});
```

html :

```
<div data-ng-repeat="webcam in datas.webcams">
 <div data-webcams data-webcam="webcam" data-margin="no"></div>
</div>
```

and data is like :
    {
    "id": 1,
    "webcam_domain": "youtube", ... etc
    }

I have this error :

```
ReferenceError: scope is not defined
    at Object.templateUrl (streamlist.js:13)
```

I don't understand, scope IS defined, no ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `scope` is not a local variable available to your templateUrl function. It is a field on the same object. You should be able to access it with `this.scope` so long as the calling angular code doesn't set `this` to another object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the scope to your `templateUrl` function as well like so:

```
templateUrl: function(scope, elem, attr)
```

Otherwise your function won't have access to it, hence your error message.

Comment: It's say me : 'Cannot read property 'webcam_domain' of undefined at Object.templateUrl (streamlist.js:13)'